# Is it possible to use the RGB inputs on a Sony PVM with an Atari STE?

Tags: atari, video

As the title states, can the RGB lines on the monitor port of the Atari ST be used with the RGB inputs on a Sony PVM CRT monitor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. The STE monitor output uses a 13 pin DIN plug/socket. This is looking at the **front** of the **plug**:

```
1   2   3   4
5   6   7   8
9   10  11  12
      13
```

7 is red channel, 6 is the green, and 10 is blue, these go to the corresponding RGB inputs on the PVM. 2 is composite sync and this should be connected to the external sync of the PVM. All grounds go to pin 13.

I created a cable using this configuration and no extra resistors/capacitors and great picture — just be sure to enable the external sync using the button on the front of the PVM!

Comment: I'll take that as a 'Yes'.

Comment: I had put RCA connectors in the back of the ST case with the RGB (sync on G) signal out; but it's so long ago I forgot any detail.. but yes, it's totally possible. Since the connector very tight, I'd recommend getting a EU cable with a SCART socket and you'll have a cable where you just modify the end.

Answer (score 6):

The Atari ST range should be able to work in 'hi res' mode, with any VGA monitor that supports the relevant resolution/frequency. These diagrams might make the pin numbering clearer, but I am afraid soldering these is difficult and not for the novice!

[image: Wiring Diagram]

[image: Pin Configuration]